# Control M unable to connect to Informatica repository

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, control-m

I am facing a problem while connecting to Informatica repository through Control M agent.
The service log shows entries of unsuccessful attempts to login with a REP_57060 error.
The work around that I have uncovered is to login to informatica using the same user which control M uses and restarting the failed workflows. Has anyone experienced the same?

Answer (score -1):

Please try calling any unix script and write the pmcmd command for the execution of the workflow in that script.It should work.